# jQuery: How to read custom object returned by Django view?

Tags: jquery, django

here is my `django view`

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def get_playlists_for_user(request):
    """
    gets all playlists for user
    """
    logging.info('getting playlist for user - ' + str(request.user))
    playlists = UserPlaylist.objects.get_all_playlists_for_user(request.user)
    logging.info('user=%s, playlists=%s'%(request.user, playlists))
    return HttpResponse(playlists)
```

Here is how `jQuery` calls it via `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/getUserPlaylists',
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){

            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        }
});
```

the view return the list of Playlist objects

```
playlists=[<Playlist id:1, name:first, date_created:2012-08-05 06:28:31.954623+00:00, deleted:False>, <Playlist id:2, name:my, date_created:2012-08-06 12:47:13.023537+00:00, deleted:False>, <Playlist id:3, name:new, date_created:2012-08-06 12:48:45.708277+00:00, deleted:False>, <Playlist id:5, name:second, date_created:2012-08-06 21:19:33.050187+00:00, deleted:False>]
```

The schema model for `Playlist` is

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When I log them in firebug I see them as

```
Playlist objectPlaylist objectPlaylist objectPlaylist object
```

How can I read these objects in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the Python objects in a form javascript can understand which is usually [json](http://www.json.org/) (javascript object notation). So in your view, convert your django queryset into json, using django's [serialisers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/):

```
from django.core import serializers
...
json = serializers.serialize('json', playlists)
return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")
```

and in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
       url: '/getUserPlaylists',
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
           for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ ){
               var playlist = response[i]['fields'];
               // Do something now with your playlist object
               console.log(playlist.name);
           }
       },
       error: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       }
});
```

this will mean the `response` in your ajax `success` will be something like this (a list of javascript objects) :

```
[{ "model" : "playlist.Playlist", "pk" : 1, "fields" : { "name" : "...", ... } }]
```

Comment: Right idea, but `json.dumps(playlists)` won't do anything useful, as `json` does not know how to serialize a queryset.

Comment: Yea, just noticed it was a QS, not an object. Just going to update