# How to access a Django object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, django

I have a Ajax function which gets the Django object from a view.

I want to access all the attributes of the object in jQuery but I am not able to do so.

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: domain+'/game/android/',                                               
    type:"POST",
    success:function(response){
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);                          
        localStorage['userCard'] = response.user_cards_held;
        localStorage['compCard'] = response.comp_cards_held;
        localStorage['game'] = response.game;                               
        alert(response.user_cards_held);// **this shows all the fields. **
        alert(response.user_cards_held.fields);//This does not work. Gives the value as undefined
        window.location = 'file:///android_asset/www/game.html';                        
    },
    error:function(xhr, status, error){
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);     

    },

});
```

View is like this:

```
    from django.core import serializers
...
json = serializers.serialize('json', objectlists)
return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")
```

Object is like this :

```
[{ "model" : "object.list", "pk" : 1, "fields" : { "name" : "...", ... } }]
```

I have checked this question :[Question Referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865818/jquery-how-to-read-custom-object-returned-by-django-view)
This does not work. 
What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

To get the field properly I have made the following changes in the success function -

```
success:function(response){
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);                          
        localStorage['userCard'] =jQuery.parseJSON(response.user_cards_held);
        localStorage['compCard'] = jQuery.parseJSON(response.comp_cards_held);
        localStorage['game'] = jQuery.parseJSON(response.game);                               
        alert(jQuery.parseJSON((response.user_cards_held));// **this shows all the fields. **
        alert(jQuery.parseJSON(response.user_cards_held.fields));//This does not work. Gives the value as undefined
        window.location = 'file:///android_asset/www/game.html';                        
    }
```

Comment: What is in the Django dict object? How does the JSON object for that look? Are you sure `.fields` is there?

Comment: @Bibhas I have made some updates please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `response.user_cards_held` is an array object -

```
>> [{ "model" : "object.list", "pk" : 1, "fields" : { "name" : "...", ... } }]
// ^----- Array
```

So of course `response.user_cards_held.fields` would be undefined. Your actual object is at `response.user_cards_held[0]` So you can access the `fields` attribute like `response.user_cards_held[0].fields`.

Comment: That means `response.user_cards_held` is a JSON string not a JSON object. You have to parse it as a JSON object first.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked fine after I parsed the other variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{ "model" : "object.list", "pk" : 1, "fields" : { "name" : "José", ... } }]

// convert JSON string to JSON Object:<br>
var data = $.parseJSON(response);<br>
// acess name atribute<br>
**data[0].fields.name**;
```

Comment: While the code may answer the question, it is always best to include a description of why your solution works and any relevant references.

Comment: @TimHutchison I prefer the "shut up and show the code" method and the code that I put is commented out. The reference is my own app, since I did not find any reference when I looked. But I'll try to improve this, thank you.